# Create/decompress Zip file with LZMA compression?

Tags: zip

According to [PKWARE's Zip Appnote](https://support.pkware.com/home/pkzip/developer-tools/appnote), it is possible to compress individual files in Zip files using LZMA (see section *5.8 LZMA - Method 14*). Support for LZMA seems to have been added around 2013.

Is there a Linux Zip tool that can create and decompress Zip files that use LZMA compression?

Comment: It might be worth noting that LZMA really shines with large data sets where it can get better compression.  The ZIP format compresses data in 32 kb chunks so the compression algorithm never gets very much data to work with and so doesn't get great compression ratios.  If you want that you should stick with lzma or 7z format with the solid option.  The trade off is that it allows for quickly accessing specific files or parts of files without having to decompress the whole thing from the beginning.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, [P7ZIP](http://p7zip.sourceforge.net/) (the port of [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/) to POSIX-style systems) can create and extract LZMA-compressed files in ZIP archives:

```
7z a -tzip -mm=LZMA ...
```

The resulting files can be listed by [Info-ZIP](http://infozip.sourceforge.net/)’s `unzip`, and their contents are correctly identified as LZMA-compressed, but `unzip` can’t extract them (it only supports ZIP 4.6-level features).

Answer (score 2):

If you are prepared to use a development version of the infozip implementation of zip, you can create zip files that use lzma compression. You need zip 3.1d or better.

There is a mirror of the source [here](https://github.com/zorba-the-geek/zip31d)

Her is a snippet of the help from zip 3.1d showing the compressed formats available

```
Compression:
  Compression method:
      -Z cm   set compression method to cm
    Valid compression methods include:
      store   - store without compression, same as option -0
      deflate - original zip deflate, same as -1 to -9 (default)
      bzip2   - use bzip2 compression (need modern unzip)
      lzma    - use LZMA compression (need modern unzip)
      ppmd    - use PPMd compression (need modern unzip)
```